# View detailed data usage/consumpotion on an iPad (running iOS 11 or later)

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to keep an eye on consumption of the 4 GB data available on a mobile data plan.

All I found thus far is consumption in GB, counting from a certain point in time (which one can easily reset) under [Settings app](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201299).

What I'd like to see is:

1. A smaller unit then GB (MB's would be good).
2. Data consumption on a per day basis.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about iOS 11, but iOS 12 uses MB as the unit if the data consumption is under a GB.

With the cellular data counter in the built-in Settings app, you are limited to the statistics shown and the option to reset counter. There's no way to further breakdown on a day/week/month basis.

You can try searching on the App Store for 3rd-party data monitoring apps. Some service provider provide their own app which tracks data usage over a period of time. If available, it would be best to use it.

Comment: maybe the "under a GB" comment is already what I need. At present it's over that already, so I may just reset the counter and likewise get more fine-grained information. thx